# insert value string into list where list in each cell of column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

My input:

```
df=(pd.DataFrame({'items':['foo','bar','xyz'],
                  'path':['c/folderOne/folderTwo/folderThree','c/folder1/folder2/folder3','c/folderO/folderT/folderTh'],
}))
```

I trying insert in column `path` some "fix" after `'c/...` I want add new substring such as `NEWPATH` into list and re-join again, but I ran *unexpected* problem.
That my code:

```
df['path'] = df['path'].map(lambda x: x.split("/"))
df['path'] = df['path'].map(lambda x: x.insert(1,'NEWPATH'))
df['path'] = df['path'].map(lambda x: x.join('/'))
```

Code return `None` in column `path`, when I **expected** something like this, after second line of my code:
in column `df['path'] : ['c','NEWPATH','folderOne'....]` etc. for each row(cell) of my column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should better use a regex here:

```
NEWPATH = 'abc'
df['path2'] = df['path'].str.replace('^([^/]+/)', rf'\1{NEWPATH}/')
```

*NB. assigning to a new column here for clarity*

output:

```
  items                               path                                  path2
0   foo  c/folderOne/folderTwo/folderThree  c/abc/folderOne/folderTwo/folderThree
1   bar          c/folder1/folder2/folder3          c/abc/folder1/folder2/folder3
2   xyz         c/folderO/folderT/folderTh         c/abc/folderO/folderT/folderTh
```

###### inserting after the nth directory:

```
NEWPATH = 'abc'
df['path2'] = df['path'].str.replace('^(^(?:[^/]+/){3})', rf'\1{NEWPATH}/')
```

or

```
NEWPATH = 'abc'
N = 3
df['path2'] = df['path'].str.replace(f'^(^(?:[^/]+/){{{N}}})', rf'\1{NEWPATH}/')
```

output:

```
  items                               path                                  path2
0   foo  c/folderOne/folderTwo/folderThree  c/folderOne/folderTwo/abc/folderThree
1   bar          c/folder1/folder2/folder3          c/folder1/folder2/abc/folder3
2   xyz         c/folderO/folderT/folderTh         c/folderO/folderT/abc/folderTh
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `insert` working inplace, so `None` is returned. You can add list to splitted `x` and then join:

```
def f(x):
    s = x.split("/")
    return '/'.join(s[:2] + ['NEWPATH'] + s[2:])
    
df['path'] = df['path'].map(f)

print (df)
  items                                       path
0   foo  c/folderOne/NEWPATH/folderTwo/folderThree
1   bar          c/folder1/NEWPATH/folder2/folder3
2   xyz         c/folderO/NEWPATH/folderT/folderTh
```

Comment: Thanks, but how add 'NEWPATH' as third item i.e. `c/folderOne/NEWPATH/...` ?

Comment: @TeoK - `df['path'] = df['path'].map(lambda x: '/'.join(x.split("/")[:2] + ['NEWPATH'] + x.split("/")[2:]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map` as well - the index *1* in the `lambda` here indicates the position where you want to insert

```
df['path'] = df['path'].str.split('/').map(lambda x: x[:1] + ['NEWPATH'] + x[1:]).str.join('/')
```